# How to include config file for variables in mocha?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I want to include config file into mocha testing framework, In this config file I want to put variable in congig which are going to use in testcases. So please tell me how to include config file in mocha. Please check the extention of config file config.js

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about a mocha test file, it can be treated just like any other js file.

config.js

```
exports.variable1 = "foo";
exports.variable2 = "bar";
```

test.js

```
var config = require('config');
var expect = require('expect');

describe("feature", function(){
    it("should work", function(){
        expect(someFunction()).to.equal(config.variable1);
        expect(someVariable).to.equal(config.variable2);
    }
}
```